# Real time web app - Which language/framework?

Tags: node.js, web-applications, websocket, real-time, java-ee-7

i'm starting to develop a web application for which I need real-time capability. In particular, as result of a server-side event (without client request), the client must refresh the view. The best solution seems to be a websocket communication.

My doubt is mainly between Node.js and JavaEE 7. Which language do you recommend for development? And with which framework?

The main requirements are:

- Interoperability with browsers
- Support for mobile devices
- Availability of tools for the creation of the graphical interface

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit broad and leads to opinion-based results - that's why it is likely to get close votes, so don't be surprised if it happens ;-)

Nevertheless, I would generally state, that "web application" and "real time" won't work together, because you have components like the network or containers in between which you don't control and thus cannot guarantee real-time requirements.

But I assume, that you are more looking for an "instant" reaction, so that your clients get informed instead of having to ask for something. In that case, web sockets are the state of the art for doing so.

Regarding technology selection, I don't think one is better than the other, it is more a question about available skills or your general programming model or customer requirements. I would think you can perfectly use Java EE 7 for that.

As a reference on that topic, I visited [Adam Bien's workshops](http://workshops.adam-bien.com/) last year and he talked about an example, where he had a huge number of clients which communicated with a Java EE app server using web sockets.